# Is there a way to tell wvdial to wait for the answer of a command?

Tags: modem, wvdial

Some `AT` commands in `wvdial` return their answers with a delay. This period of time depends on the command. For instance, when you want to scan for available networks, you can use the `AT+COPS=?` command. The scanning process takes about 30s, but `wvdial` doesn't wait until it's finished and resend the command. After the second try, `wvdial` gives up with the following error:

```
# wvdial info-scan
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: AT+COPS=?
--> Re-Sending: AT+COPS=?
--> Modem not responding.
```

After some time (30s), I can issue another command via `wvdial`, it can be anything, for instance `ATZ+CFUN=1`, which does nothing when the modem is already on, but after sending the command, I get the output from the previous one:

```
# wvdial modem-start
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ+CFUN=1
+COPS: (2,"T-Mobile.pl","TM PL","26002",2),(1,"T-Mobile.pl","TM
PL","26002",7),(3,"Plus","PLUS","26001",7),
(3,"Play","Play","26006",7),(3,"Orange","Orange","26003",7),
(3,"Play","Play","26006",2),(3,"Orange","Orange","26003",2),
(3,"Plus","PLUS","26001",2),,(0,1,2,3,4),(0,1,2)
OK
```

So is there a way to set some kind of timeout for the commands so they could get the delayed answer?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by some trick to create this python script, it will wait for approximately 40seconds or a minute:

```
import serial
import subprocess
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/modem0', 460800, timeout=2)

cmd = 'AT+COPS=0\r\n'
ser.write(cmd)
ser.sendBreak()

s = []
time_now = time.time()
while(time.time()-time_now)<=40:
    newdata = ser.read()
    if newdata is not None or newdata!="":
            global s
            s.append(newdata)
ser.close
print "".join(s)

subprocess.Popen(["wvdial"])
```